# How to run recorded selenium test case in standalone servcer using spring/java

Tags: java, spring, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-server

I have recorded few application test cases and I need to schedule and run it selenium standalone using java.

Can someone guide on it.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Jenkin and Nimbus screenshot & screen video recorder addon. You can achieve the above request.

Jenkin - CI tool. You can schedule and run the test .

NSSVR - Add the Nssvr.crx in browser capability. with the help of shortcut key , you can start, stop and save the recorder.